# Power BI report exported in PDF file is not showing complete data

Tags: powerbi

After exporting report in PDF format from Power BI desktop, it is showing only visible area data but not the complete table data which was available and visible after scroll down in Power BI Desktop report page.

Comment: This is by design. Power BI is an interactive tool. Use something else, Paginated Reports for example, if you want to print the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated the report in PDF format with complete data using below steps:

1. Prepared the Datasource using Power BI Desktop application and pushed it to Power BI Services in my workspace there.
2. Accessed the datasource from Power BI Services using Power BI report biulder and converted it to Dataset in Power BI report builder.
3. Got the DAX query from Power BI desktop application for same datasource to get the report from Power BI paginated report builder.
4. For more info, please go through the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-shared-datasets